# Visual Studio wcf client c# SOAP evenlope method name with different case

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, case-sensitive

I have a C# WCF client that should call a third part WCF web service: the misfortune of the web service is that the parameter type is equal to the method name and change only the case sensitive: when i make the following call where the type of the variable **lclassname** has the same name of the method **ClassName** (change only the case sensitive):

```
var lclassName = new className()
...
...
var lreturnValue = new ClassName(lclassName);
```

I have noticed in the raw XML request that Visual Studio make a thing like this when i try to call the web service using the client class Reference.cs build by Visual Studio throught the **Add Service reference** function:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <ClassName xmlns="">
            <ClassName...>
            
            </ClassName...>
        </ClassName...>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I have traced the SOAP raw http request made by Visual Studio throught the System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener in web.config.
if you note Visual Studio change the first case letter of the type of the parameter. Why?
I call a web service of third party and i can't change the type of the parameter.
Is there a way to say to Visual Studio when call WCF client throught SOAP not to change the names of the methods? (For example with some attributes or some options in endpoint web.config)

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on whether the first letter of your ClassName is uppercase or lowercase. Calling the WCF service through the VS generation agent will not change the first letter of ClassName.